# JUnit @After method calls before second test

Tags: java, junit

I have class called `TestBase` and two methods `setUp()` and `tearDown()`. There is code of these methods:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    app = ApplicationManager.getInstance();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    app.stop();
}
```

Also I have two classes which extends from `TestBase` and has method with `@Test` annotation:

```
public class SubscriptionTests extends TestBase<Subscription> {

@Test
public void testValidSubscription() {
    DataGenerator.createTestData(Subscription.class);
    Subscription subscription = (Subscription) getFromXml("subscription", new String[]{"email"}).get(0);
    app.getModelHelper().createModel(subscription);
}   
 }

public class UserRegistrationTests extends TestBase<User> {

@Test
public void testRegistrationValidUser() {
    DataGenerator.createTestData(User.class);
    List<BaseModel> users = getFromXml("user", new String[]{ "email", "name", "password", "passwordConfirmation"});
    User validUser = (User) users.get(0);
    app.getModelHelper().createModel(validUser);
}}
```

I try start tests. The first one ends with success, but after that calls method `tearDown()` in `TestBase` class (with `@After` annotation) and I get `SessionNotFoundException`. As a result the second test doesn't start. What's wrong?

Comment: what is that exception? Maybe you should find it's cause and start from there?

Answer (score 2):

`@Before` and `@After` mark (instance) methods to run before and after each test respectively. Perhaps you want `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` which mark (static) methods to run once only at the very beginning and end respectively.

Comment: Can you supply the stack trace (in the question)? Did you convert your methods and `app` to static?